# How to change the Menu Bar color on Blogger

Tags: blogger

I own [this blog](http://un-francais-a-new-york.blogspot.com/).  I'd like to change the font and background color of the Menu Bar.  Any idea how to do it?  Can't seem to find the code anywhere...  Thanks!

Comment: You can try searching for ".tabs-inner .widget ul" in the blogger template. There must be a css anywhere.. if there is not then add it to override default. and Set the background as per required..

Answer (score 2):

```
Follow these steps:         
 1. From the blog Dashboard, go to Template -> Edit HTML-> Proceed -> put a check mark in front of the the "Expand Widget Templates" option (details: same as the first 3 steps in this post)

 2. On your keyboard press the "Ctrl" and "F" keys at same time to bring up the search box.

 3. In the search box  you type in (or copy) this highlighted codes .tabs-inner

    .tabs-inner {
            padding:0
      }

 4.  Add following one line code above } symbol:

      background-color:#6baa4a;

 Note: 

 #6baa4a is the color code for the green color I'm using. You can replace it with any other color code you want. If you have no idea of the color code, you can search "HTML color" in Google.

  5. Make sure to save the change by clicking on "Save Template" button at the top-right corner. Done !

  Go back to your blog and refresh your webpage, you will see your favorite background color showing up for your top tab menu bar !
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your dashboard

Click on Template > Edit template > Advanced > Header bar > Choose color > Apply to Blog ( top right orange button ) and that's it.